# Can I include a javascript file in to a blazor page ( razor component)

Tags: javascript, blazor-webassembly

I am new to Blazor.

We want to build a website by Blazor WASM.
Our website have couple pages, these pages are razor files under "Pages" folder and some pages need to use javascript.

From what I know I can include the js file in index.html, but this js file will be included in all my pages.

Can I include a js file just to my target razor page?

For example, I have a "Counter" page, I need run some js only for Counter page. Can I include the js file only in this "Counter" page?

Thanks for anybody willing to help!

Comment: I firgured out by following post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67560407/include-javascript-component-into-blazor-component